# jPlayer: Stop when condition is false

Tags: javascript, jplayer

I am using a flash detection script to determine the flash support on a browser.
I want jPlayer to stop when flash is enabled. This doesn't seem to work so far.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(!FlashDetect.installed){
        $("#audioplayer").hide();      
    }else{
        $("#jp_container_1").hide();
        $("#startpage_jplayer").jPlayer("mute");
        $("#startpage_jplayer").jPlayer("stop");     
    }
})
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You need to be much more specific. Is the flashdetect if/else statement working? Also this code needs to be after you have initialized jPlayer, if not then their won't be a jPlayer to stop. Show your jPlayer code.

Comment: My code runs after the initialization of the player. The statement works perfectly ! I will post my code when I arrive at my office. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to repeat something over and over again, you need to put it in a loop.

```
if (!FlashDetect.installed)
{
    $("#audioplayer").hide();
}
else 
{
    while(!FlashDetect.installed){ } // This line will happen as long as (!FlashDetect.installed) is true

    // This stuff will happen when (!FlashDetect.installed) is false (Flash is installed)
    $("#jp_container_1").hide();
    $("#startpage_jplayer").jPlayer("mute");
    $("#startpage_jplayer").jPlayer("stop");
}
```

**Note, that my code above will probably cause the browser to stop responding.** 
But that is the basis of a loop.

Instead, and a better method, check if it is installed on an *interval*

```
if (!FlashDetect.installed)
{
    $("#audioplayer").hide();
}
setInterval(function(){
    if (FlashDetect.installed)
    {
        $("#jp_container_1").hide();
        $("#startpage_jplayer").jPlayer("mute");
        $("#startpage_jplayer").jPlayer("stop");

     }
}, 20000);
```

This code is much better, it will check if flash is installed every 20 seconds, and if it is, then it will stop jPlayer.

You can read about [setInterval() here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

Comment: Why would you need to check continuously for flash support? He doesn't want/need to check continuously I presume, his code just doesn't work which this answer doesn't address I don't think.

Comment: @MartinMazzaDawson The way OP phrased the question sounds like he wants to stop jPlayer after it has started, that's why I continuously check for it.